# why google_ml_kit flutter library [Google ML kit vision] took large size while taking flutter ios / android build?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-mlkit

I'm just using it for text detection only.

below code added in   manifest file ,but no changes in the build right now ,still it takes too much size. How to solve this issue.
this is the flutter package I'm using.
https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
              <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr" />
```

Comment: The "google_ml_kit" is neither owned or endorsed by Google or ML Kit team. Please use their support page (https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues) to report issues or asking quesitons.

Comment: Yes , Thank you ,I thought that package was famous.

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest version. `google_ml_kit` has been split in multiples plugins, to avoid adding unnecessary dependencies in your project. You can start using `google_mlkit_text_recognition` instead.

More details here:

- https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/tree/master/packages/google_ml_kit
- https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/tree/master/packages/google_mlkit_text_recognition